# Create an array of strings of all possible combination of the elements of a series of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, bioinformatics

I would like to do *reverse DNA translation* using [BioRuby](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bioruby/bioruby/Bio/CodonTable:revtrans) which offers a nice CODON table for bacterias.

Here a code snippet describing the series of arrays I have (they are a lot more!).

```
# Arrays Sample
a = table.revtrans("A") # ["gct", "gcc"]
b = table.revtrans("M") # ["atg"]
c = table.revtrans("L") # ["tta", "ttg", "ctt", "ctc", "cta", "ctg"]
d = ...
```

I would like to create an array or hash with all possible combinations of the above strings.

```
["gctatgtta", "gccatgtta", "gtcatgttg", "gctatgctt", etc]
```

Any idea how can I achieve this using Ruby? I tried using the `combination` method, but failed to produce any sensible result. Also, I'd like to be able to predetermine the number of computations if possible! So please offer some mathematical explanation if you can!

#### Some Explanation

These 3-letter strings are **DNA codons**. Each triplet can be translated into an [amino acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid) from a pre-determined [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table). What I'm doing is essentially creating a (huge) series of potential DNA sequences from which a protein could be produced theoretically.

Thanks!

Comment: You need that from each array one element will be chosen, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[*a, *b, *c].combination(3).map &:join
 #=> ["gctgccatg", "gctgcctta", #...`

Answer (score 4):

What you want to use is [`product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-product).

> Returns an array of all combinations of elements from all arrays.
>
> The length of the returned array is the product of the length of self
>   and the argument arrays.

```
%w(gct gcc).product(%w(atg), %w(tta ttg)).map(&:join)

# => ["gctatgtta", "gctatgttg", "gccatgtta", "gccatgttg"]
```

Comment: `product` can take more than one argument, so something like `a.product(b, c)` might be simpler.